# Data Storage in Ethereum

Tags: contract-design, storage

How does data storage work in Ethereum? Do variables of a Smart Contract map to columns of a table? And an update to those variables creates a new record with their latest values?

So if 100 employees of an organization have updated their basic details on Blockchain by calling the Smart Contract 100 times - one call from each employee, how is the data stored? How can the calling program retrieve an existing record? Is there a primary key?

Comment: Perhaps you want to create a new question on how to store efficiently company/employees information in a Smart contract. Smart contracts are not very good at storing lots of data. To organize data inside a contract you can use solidity mappings.